# Is Omega-3 Consumption Associated with Lowering of LDL cholesterol?

Tags: blood, supplement, cholesterol, omega-3

I found some conflicting information on whether omega-3 consumption is associated with decreased LDL levels.

[This](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/high-cholesterol-foods#lowering-cholesterol) says:

> Increase dietary omega-3s: **Consuming more omega-3-rich foods like
> wild-caught salmon or taking omega-3 supplements like fish oil pills
> have been shown to reduce LDL and raise HDL levels (50**

But [this](https://www.verywellhealth.com/can-fish-oil-omega-3-fatty-acids-lower-cholesterol-698137):

> **Omega-3 fats can slightly raise your low-density lipoprotein (LDL)**
> cholesterol. This change, however, is modest and ranges from 3% to
> 10%.

The two statement seem to suggest opposite effects.

Omega-3 compounds appear to be widely used [in medicine as therapeutics](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3875260/).

What is the overall evidence of omega-3 consumption with direction of LDL cholesterol level?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions regarding diet and nutrition are off topic here unless directly related to medical treatments.

Comment: @CareyGregory Then which stack exchange web site is suitable? Also why is it diet, when cholesterol is serious medical condition ???

Comment: I have submitted an [edit](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27871) which I think makes this question on topic for MedicalSciences.SE and have voted to reopen.

Comment: @user24417 There is no SE site that accepts diet and nutrition questions. Just because you think a subject is important doesn't mean a site has to accept those questions. It's a decision made by the community, not by any individual.